# How to add FormControl dynamically to FormGroup in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to build a data-table compatible with FormGroup & FormArray. I will pass header details and rows to this component with parentForm group.

I have created a small add button, on clicking it, I will add new items dynamically. In this case, UI is updating fine, but if I print formGroup.value(), I am getting only the initial value passed. Not the updated formControl. I'm not sure what I am missing.

```
export class FormTableComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() headers: Array<string>;
    @Input() rows: Array<any>;
    @Input() parentFG: FormGroup;
    @Input() entriesName: string;

    get entries(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.parentFG.get(this.entriesName);
    }

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.createFormControls();
    }

    createFormControls() {
        this.parentFG.controls[this.entriesName] = this.fb.array([]);
        this.rows.forEach(row => {
            this.entries.controls.push(this.fb.group(row));
        });
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNzLsF4C0vMRsFzcTou7?p=preview)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:
1. you push new row to controls of FormArray other than FormArray itself

```
this.entries.controls.push(this.fb.group(row));
```

should be

```
this.entries.push(this.fb.group(row));
```

2. don't create new FormArray everytime and reload every single row when invoke `createFormControls()`, you can access it by your `get entries()` method

Solution 1:

Check length of `entries`, if it is 0, initialize it with `rows` otherwise just push last row into the existing `FormArray`

```
createFormControls() {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.entries.value);
        if( keys.length === 0) {
          this.rows.forEach(row => {
              this.entries.push(this.fb.group(row));
          });
        } else {
          const row = this.rows[this.rows.length - 1];
          this.entries.push(this.fb.group(row));
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:

Personally, I prefer putting `createFormArray()` and `appendTo()` or `popFrom()` into the parent Component. It is clean and easy read. We don't need `ChangeDetectionRef` in this case.

I have moved `createFormControls()` from `form-table` component to `dummy` component and rename it to `createFormArray()` and changed `addNewRow()` a little bit, now everything works properly

```
// create FormArray once
createFormArray() {
    const elements: any[] =[];

    this.rows.forEach(row => {
        elements.push(this.fb.group(row));
    });
    return this.fb.array(elements);
}

addNewRow() {
  const newRow =    {
            name: 'NAFFD',
            age: 12,
            place: 'TN'
        };

    this.rows.push(newRow);  // update rows

    const persons =  this.dummyForm.get('persons') as FormArray;
    persons.push(this.fb.group(newRow));  // update FormArray
}
```

When initializing your dummy form, do below:

```
   this.dummyForm = this.fb.group({
        persons: this.createFormArray(),
        store: this.fb.group({
            branch: '',
            code: ''
        })
    });
```

[image]

Hope it helps and happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

This is a common misconception about `ngOnChanges`. `ngOnChanges` works best with [Primitive Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), because they are passed by value.

Objects and Arrays in Javascript are passed by reference. That being said, `ngOnChanges` is looking for the value of the input provided to change. In this case, **the reference to your Array is the input provided**, not the values within the Array. So unless you are passing a new Array into the component, `ngOnChanges` will not fire, thus not re-rendering your form.

One quick and dirty solution could be to re-instantiate the Object/Array everytime you update it on the Parent side.

```js
this.rows = Object.assign([], newRows);
```

This would create an entirely new array, which should in turn change the reference, and finally force `ngOnChanges` to fire on the child.

Alternatively you could somehow convert your Rows into an `Observable` and subscribe to it within the child. Personally, Observables are a much cleaner way to deal with Change Detection outside of Primitive Types. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) is a great writeup from the docs on Parent/Child Communication through a Service.

Comment: Yes, if you see my code, I am already creating new array and sending like you said above. It doesn't helps.